# How to create a Swift framework that depends on other frameworks (RxSwift ...)

Tags: ios, swift, frameworks, cocoapods, fastlane

I'm developing a swift framework that depends on RxSwift, It works well when Debug.
Then I build it by fastlane and upload to cocoapods.
Then I create a new Project and try my framework by cocoapods.
However,when code run to my framework, and it crash At

```
RxSwift.PublishSubject line 93:
self.lock.performLocked { self.synchronized_subscribe(observer) }    ⚠️Thread 1: signal SIGABRT
```

log:

```
objc[1257]: Attempt to use unknown class 0x2829f0a20.
```

There is my build code with fastlane

```
xcodebuild(
      project:"Pods/Pods.xcodeproj",
      scheme:"BVSweeperKit",
      configuration: "Release",
      silent: true,
      clean: true, 
      build:true,
      xcargs: "-UseModernBuildSystem=0 -sdk 'iphonesimulator'"
      )
```

There is my podspec:

```
  s.swift_versions = '5.0'
  s.ios.deployment_target = '11.0'
  s.vendored_frameworks = 'lib/*.xcframework'
  s.static_framework = true
  
  s.dependency 'RxSwift', '6.2.0'
  s.dependency 'RxCocoa', '6.2.0'
  s.dependency 'RxRelay', '6.2.0'
  s.dependency 'GZIP', '1.3.0'
  s.dependency 'SnapKit', '5.0.1'
  s.dependency 'SwiftyJSON', '5.0.1'
```

My new project Pod just pod my framework.

How can I fix my crash? Or how to build my framework and upload to cocoapods?
Any Answer will help me?
Thanks

Comment: I don't know what the issue is. But i can give you a huge advice. Stop with RxSwift, and stop with cocoapods. you are shooting yourself in the foot :/

Comment: @Vollan Is it bad to use a different framework when making a framework?

Comment: @김지태 Yes it is, and it's strictly prohibited by apple and you will at times have problems with releases if you have nested frameworks